# jquery console log object changes zero to NaN

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome

This is the output of the chrome (59.0.3071.115) console. How is it possible that same key has different values (0 and NaN)?

this also stays when I .log variable and `JSON.parse` result separately.

`console.log(variable)` changes `0` to `NaN`, but `console.log(JSON.parse(json_string))` outputs `0`.

```
Object {name: "US", weight: 0, etfs: Array(1)}
    etfs:Array(1)
    name:"US"
    weight:NaN
    __proto__:Object
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code which produces this behaviour as I am unable to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/qujcft02/

Comment: Provide the jQuery code that generates this error, in order for us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: var custom_portfolio = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('custom_portfolio'));
    console.log(custom_portfolio);
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('custom_portfolio')));

Comment: @Alexander could you please either create a jsFiddle, or append your code as a snippet in your question. Nobody likes to read unparsed code. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander that's half of what we need. What is the *content* of the localStorage properties you set? Even just updating the fiddle with that doesn't produce what you decribe: https://jsfiddle.net/qujcft02/2/

Comment: a code is a bit huge, i will made a jsfiddle, wait a sec
here https://jsfiddle.net/t8pmekvw/

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: That also does not display the behaviour you describe. The console output is still `weight: 0`

Comment: trying to reproduce it out of code, will post it here after